# Как в конструкторе определить размер массива?

Tags: c++

```
class vector {
    public: int x;
        vector();
        int ar[10];
};

vector::vector(int size):ar{} {

}
```

Comment: Это не лучшая правка вопроса. Код должен быть в формате [mcve], т.е. без лишнего мусора.

Comment: @alexout Как раз подходит под мой вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Написать где то так

```
class vector {
    public: int x;
        vector();
        explicit vector(int size);
        ~vector();
        int ar_size
        int* ar;
};

vector::vector() {
    ar_size = 0;
    ar = nullptr; // NULL для старых компиляторов
}

vector::vector(int size) {
    ar_size = size;
    ar = new int[ar_size];
}

vector::~vector() {
    delete[] ar;
}
```

замечания:

- называть класс vector - не совсем хорошо. Возможен конфликт с `std::vector`.
- вместо int для размера лучше использовать size_t
- `ar` и `ar_size` лучше внести в приватную часть, что бы наружу не торчало.

Comment: На то и пространства имён, чтоб конфликтов не возникало. И вы забыли `[]` при удалении.

Comment: да, скобки забыл. А конфликты лучше просто не допускать (если есть такая возможность)

Comment: Не допускать - это типа называть классы VendorProjectVector? Каким образом возможен конфликт классов в разных namespace?

Comment: @vp_arth при добавлении `using namespace std;` конечно :) В заголовочный файл. Хехе

Comment: Я подправил вопрос.

Comment: не нужно бросаться в крайности. Скорее всего в вопросе обычный учебный проект. Поэтому, я бы назвал как my_vector/foo_vector и не переживал бы. А если это серьезный проект - тогда  там  и так прекрасно знают, как именовать и неймспейсы использовать. А вот за `VendorProjectVector` - это очень печальное имя.

Comment: @aaa это не "я поправил". Это "я переписал".

Comment: Хм, похоже, что конфликт таки имеет место быть хД

Comment: Ошибка: prototype for 'vector::vector(int)' does not match any in class 'vector'|

Comment: поправил, плюс добавил explicit.

Comment: Ошибка на диструкторе: definition of implicitly-declared 'vector::~vector()'|